# Handling discord.py specific errors in on_command_error() event

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My discord bot uses the same command prefix as another bot in the server, this causes the console to spam a `CommandNotFound` error every time someone uses the other bot. I saw another question where someone answered that you can handle the error like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    #print(error) -- returns error description
    if (error == CommandNotFound):
        return
    raise error
```

But this solution just throws a NameError saying that `CommandNotFound` was not found. I also tried this after seeing that the console output said `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound` instead of `CommandNotFound` like other python specific errors.

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if (error == (discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound)):
         return
    raise error
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Is error parameter an object or a class? Have you tried using `isinstance` instead? Since the raise works, it should already be an object, hence, you have to first compare the type, preferably using `isinstance`.

Comment: Also, according the doc, the exception is located under `discord.ext.commands.CommandNotFound`. Have you imported it using `from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're getting a `NameError`, it means that what you're referencing doesn't exist (i.e. isn't defined) in the scope where you refer to it. You need to import `CommandNotFound`:

```
from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound
```

Then check for it:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    # Or, if you've already imported `commands`, you could write
    # commands.CommandNotFound here instead of explicitly importing it.
    if isinstance(error, CommandNotFound):  # Using `==` is incorrect
        return
    raise error
```